# Twitter Typeahead updater

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, bloodhound

Can anyone see what I have done wrong here? I have spent ages looking at a whole variety of typeahead code.  Values are returned from the Json call that I can select, but I need to set the Id hidden field.  I have tried all sorts in the updater function (log, alerts etc.) but zip. I believe its not triggering.

```
    var teamNames = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('Text'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: 'List'
});

teamNames.initialize();

$('#remote #FullName').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'team-names',
    displayKey: 'Text',
    source: teamNames.ttAdapter(),
    updater: function(item){$('#Id').val(map[item].Value)}
})
```

Thanks a lot for any observations.  If you think you have an answer please set as an answer so I can acknowledge - cheers.

Update - I suspect I have used some out of date or incompatible code. I have now used

```
 $('#FullName').bind('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum, name) {}
```

that I found here [on GitHub](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/300), thanks andy3rdworld, which works perfectly

Comment: Can you give us an example of the full code now it is working, @TimH?

Comment: Would also be interested in this if at all possible.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem... I think we were relying on an example using an old version of typehead... /:

Typehead [**uses events**](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events) now... Here's [**the example**](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/300) ended up following...

Answer (score 1):

Bloodhound Suport Type Head like this

```
var numSelectedHandler = function(eventObject, suggestionObject, suggestionDataset) {
        $('#postal_code').typeahead('val', suggestionObject.key);
    };
$('#postal_code').on('typeahead:selected', numSelectedHandler);
```